# How do I bulk insert markdown data into Postgres

Tags: postgresql, next.js

I am working on Nextjs project. I am trying to insert some JSON data into Postgres database. The data is in markdown and it contains lot of unescaped characters code snippets  ``"r"i""n$'t\u0066'` like this. It's not possible to insert that data as a JSON. Is there any way to insert this data?